# How to get the param which content-type is x-www-form-urlencoded in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, parameter-passing, httprequest, getter-setter

The request is like this:
[image]

In server,I have a bean like this:

```
@Data
public class TechInfo {
    private int shopID;    
    private String name;   
    private int experience;   
    TechnicianTitleInfo technicianTitleInfo;  
    private String skill;
}
```

How can I get the request params in Struts2 ?

I've declared a TechInfo in my action, but its value is null after Struts2 parsed it.

The action is like this:

```
public class AjaxAction{

    @Getter @Setter private TechInfo techInfo;

    protected void jsonExecute() throws Exception {
      //need the techInfo
    }
}
```

Comment: Which method is `jsonExecute()`, where is it called (clearly not an action method, since it's `void`) ? Can you show the interceptor stack used for this call, and possibly the JSP snippet containing the parameters too ?

Comment: @yonney.yang you are using wrong parameter name to populate action property, either you change the name or retrieve parameters manually.

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter format is the one using the **Dot Notation**:

```
techInfo.picID
techInfo.name
techInfo.technicianTitleInfo.titleId
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the param which content-type is x-www-form-urlencoded

Struts2 is using `request.getParameterMap()`.

> I've declared a TechInfo in my action, but its value is null after Struts2 parsed it.

The value is `null` because `TechInfo` isn't bound to the action class variable. Request parameter name should be the same as variable name `techInfo`.